# Run 2 runs, run 2 (can "runs" be dropped in colloquial language) [cricket]

Tags: word-usage, british-english, informal-language

I had a question related to Cricket. Colloquially, where the context's obvious, can "runs" be dropped to avoid duplication?

> The batsman  ran two runs.

But can it be (in a obvious context)

> The batsman ran two.
>
> ---
>
> The batsman should try to run two.
>
> The batsman should try for two.

Do all the sentences above sound natural? And do the last two sentences sound natural?

Answer (score 2):

While batsmen may **hit/score/take two runs** or **make two runs**, they DON'T **run two runs**. It's not idiomatic.

Instead, as you suggest, **ran two** is fine when the context is already established. You will often hear expressions such as:

> they take an easy two....
>   they scurry home for two...
>   they snatch two (runs)....

and so on.

Comment: And what about: The batsman took two runs.

Comment: Does it sound natural?

Comment: And does "The batsman ran two" sound natural?  I thought  that I had just dropped  "runs".  And what about the last two sentences?

Comment: Does "run two " suggest  "run two times"?

Comment: I read "run two runs" at a lot of places....

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Google Books Ngram Viewer records multiple instances of **take two runs** and NONE of **run two runs**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+two+runs

Comment: "run two runs" is completely normal - it is often abreviated, but is arguably the most grammatically correct version. I cannot explain why Ngram hasn't picked it up - that is VERY strange.

Comment: @MikeBrockington **Run two runs** may be grammatical but it's not idiomatic. That's to say, you won't hear it from cricket commentators. I speak as a former player and coach and as a frequent listener.

Comment: @RonaldSole  Frequent watcher/listener and ex-player too, and it is a perfectly common expression.